# Concatenate multiple rows into one row (But not a as a string)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 iD     PhoneNumber    EmailAddress
 1       06543635463    NULL
 1       NULL           Me@Me.com
 2       NULL           You@You.net
 2       0298754355     NULL
 3       0543280545     NULL
```

And I'm tryong to concatenate the rows so they look like this:

```
id    PhoneNumber      EmailAddress
1     06543635463      Me@Me.com
2     0298754355       You@You.net
3     0543280545       NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: So which data type do you want?

Comment: That would be deduplication, not concatenation.

Comment: I guess you inserted records instead of update for same `ID`.

Answer (score 7):

That's not a *concatenation*, it's a simple *aggregation*. Sounds like you could use `MIN`  or `MAX`:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(PhoneNumber) PhoneNumber,
       MAX(EmailAddress) EmailAddress
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY id;
```